# Label Array in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, arrays, label

I have 10 labels (Label1, Label2, Label3, Label4, etc...) in an `Array` and I need to change the `Text` property with a timer, I have the timer working well, but I don't know how to change one Label at the time( this second the label1, the next second label2, the next second label3...etc)...

I'm using VB.NET with the .NET 4.0 Framework in Visual Studio.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question was closed because it was rather difficult to understand without the context of the code that you mention. In the future, you'll get better answers much faster if you provide the relevant bits of code that help put your problem in context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the timer set up and working already, try something like this for your array:

```
'These will be your labels:
Dim oLabel As New Label
Dim oLabel2 As New Label

'Create the array from your labels:
Dim aLabels() As Label = {oLabel, oLabel2}

'loop through your array:
For each oLabel as Label in aLabels

  oLabel.Text = "your text value here"

Next
```

Comment: And how I create a Label Array in the form?...

Comment: check out my updated code sample. This will show you how to put your labels into an array. You can list as many as you want in those curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with something like this:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class Form1
Private _labels As Label()

Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    InitalizeLabelArray()
End Sub

Private Sub InitalizeLabelArray()
    _labels = New Windows.Forms.Label() {Label1, Label2, Label3}
End Sub


End Class
```

Answer (score -1):

VB.NET is not VB6 and [does not have control arrays](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/l/bldykctrlarraya.htm).

There are ways to emulate them (adding them to a collection and looping over the collection), or using the [`Form.Controls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx) collection and only acting on `Label` controls, for example.