# Is it possible to select labels with integers?

Tags: vb.net, label

Is it possible to mark Label with an integer?

```
Dim nr As Integer = 1

Do
Label(nr).text = "something"
nr += 1
Loop until nr = 4
```

And then it would fill up the labels

EDIT:
I wanted to know if it was possible to create Label arrays.
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390510/label-array-in-vb-net) article nad put together my own method.

```
label1.Text = "test1"
    label2.Text = "test2"

    label1.Location = New Point(120, 80)
    label2.Location = New Point(140, 20)

    Me.Controls.Add(label1)
    Me.Controls.Add(label2)

    Dim labels() As Label = {label1, label2}

    For Each label As Label In labels
        label.Text = "new test"
    Next
```

Comment: why not set the label text to a integer.tostring()

Comment: i think you should either go learn programming or rephrase your question.

Comment: Do you want to create an array of labels? I don't understand exactly what you want to do.

Comment: I want a loop to fill up the labels, and I want nr variable to control the next label to be filled

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your example, you probably just aren't running though the correct array or the array is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the label name in the control collection of the form the labels are displayed on.

```
   For i as integer = 0 to 49 Step 1
      Me.Controls("Label" & i.toString).Text = "Something"
   Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
Dim lbl As Label() = New Label(9) {}
Dim nr As Integer = 0

Do
    lbl(nr) = New Label()
    lbl(nr).Text = "somthing " & nr
    nr += 1
Loop While nr <> 4
```

Comment: it creates an array of labels and adds text to the first 4 of them.

Comment: @KaurPalang -  It appears to do nothing because the labels are not placed on a form with their Visible properties set to True.